# Can't use the get method for PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, twilio

I need to place the two form inputs into a php script. I use the get method, but when i try to run the code on my webserver i get a 500 error.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>SMS</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="send_besked.php" method="get">
Tlf:: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
Besked: <input type="text" name="msg"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the send_besked.php

```html
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'xxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxx';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    '($_GET["number"])',
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => '+19152282067',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => 'echo ($_GET["msg"])'
    )
);
```

I had deletede my access token and my sid.

Comment: Do you have access to your server log? 500 errors will write something to the log that gives you some idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use POST(in form tag) method when you are submitting data to server?Generally GET is used to get data from the server and POST is for submitting data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I made it to a post script and deleted the following symbols

```html
'
```

Thank you for your help